# When to have a deep discussion about the employer's company

Tags: recruitment

I have only participated in a few recruitment processes and am currently in my first formal job since graduation.

I have also recently been contacted by recruiters from potential companies, and I am very eager to learn about them, so I have accepted an invitation for a coffee discussion with one of them.

My question is, *when (in which stage of the recruitment process)can I ask about the employer's company (vision, career development opportunities, how I can be of use/contribution to them, etc.) and how long does this kind of conversation take (1 hour, 2 hours, etc.)?* Is it during the first interview or maybe informal conversation? or at the final interview? Please share your thoughts and experiences.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

I usually hit them with questions like that at the first interview, it usually doesn't take 1-2 hours but may add on an extra 20-30 minutes to the interview.

No point wasting each others time if I don't like where the company is going, interviews are a two way street.

Comment: It's important not to ask basic questions about what the company does that can be learned from their website. I had one of my first interviews cut short because, when asked what I knew about the company, I drew a blank and couldn't recall what I had read about them the night before.

Comment: It is amazing how many interviews you can (and will) stuff up with little things like that.  I'm a walking example.

Answer (score 2):

This is completely up to you, Personally I would do it in the first interview as you can show the employer that;

A) You are interested in the company and are thinking about the future

B) You show that you know where you want to be in the future.

> How long does this kind of conversation take?

This also is completely dependant on how in depth the companies goals are, what they aim to get out of you and how the general conversation flow goes but I would say your estimates of 1-2 hours are quite accurate in terms of an estimate but some can be as short as 10-20 mins

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this sort of discussion takes place at the final interview (not much pint, until it is sure that the candidate maybe be a good fit).

That being said, it helps to find out a lot about the company beforehand. Before the first interview , in fact.

Look at their web site to find out what they do, and if it is of interest to you. For instance, I am an embedded software developer and can tell immediately if a company is not going to be a fit for me. You might find that the company does defence work, etc, to which you are morally opposed. In that case, there won’t even be a first interview (your choice).

If you like the look of the company, their product line can give you an idea of what you might be doing. Their web site might mention the number of employees. I fit doesn’t, you can probably Google it. But the number of offices, and countries in which they operate, can give you a feel.  Maybe you would prefer a small, cozy,  “family feel”. A multinational might offer overseas assignment for a few years.

A bonus of this is that employers except you have some knowledge of the company; to at least have shown some interest (oh, that dreaded “why do you want to work for *us*” question!).

To get more towards an actual answer to your question (at last :-) For a permanent position, I would generally expect a telephone interview and two rounds of face to face.

For a software job (I  can only speak for that field, but imagine it will be much the same elsewhere), the first round is a sort of nuts & bolts, technical interview, while the second is more “corporate fit”.

That is to say, the first finds out if the candidate can actually code, which a technical test & some talk. At that point, as the candidate (I am also often an interview), I generally ask about development methods, planning, documentation, tools used, testing, … there will be a bi tat the end, “do you have any questions for us?”. Generally that is the last 10 minutes of an hour, but unless the interviewer has a meeting immediately following, it can go further; if not, save such questions for the second round, when their will be more time.. Btw, asking such questions makes you an attractive candidate; I would advise you to prepare some in advance.

The second round is where you can address your questions

> vision, career development opportunities, how I can be of
>   use/contribution to them

For software, since you have proved that you can actually talk the talk, we start to discuss with you how we, as a company, walk the walk, and see if/how, you can fit in.  In my experience, most fall at the  first hurdle, and not many flunk out here (YMMV).

We will explain about the project that we see you starting on. I, as a tech interviewer, will explain where our technologies might be heading, etc. HR are more likely do ask you about expected career development.  Don’t be shy about being ambitious, it can be a good trait.

Since we like you, and want to have you on board (after a ‘phone call & tech interview), HR will be present and will explain/try to sell the company to you. You will be told about career growth and benefits, such as pension, holiday, training, etc, etc That may well answer much of your questions anyway (side note, that doesn’t guarantee that you will receive an offer, but the longer that they speak, the more like it is).

And, finally, there comes “do you have any questions”, which is what you were mainly asking about. It certainly helps to have some, although saying “I did, but you already answered them, thanks” is acceptable (advice. Don’t just mumble or say “no”). That will last as long as you want it too, until both sides are aware of what you might want and how they might fulfil it, while you bring value to the company.

Sorry if I rambled a little, this started as a single line :-)